# WRT54G2 unable to pick up IP address

Tags: wireless-router

Whenever I connect my new router to my cable modem, it is unable to get an IP address from the modem. The address always comes up as 0.0.0.0. DHCPC renew does not change anything. What might be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your ISP require you to register your router MAC?  Does your ISP use PPPOE?  If the answer to both of these questions is "No" then it is likely you powered up your modem and router in the wrong order.  Make sure you plug your modem FIRST, wait 10 seconds, then plug your router in.

Comment: Good point about powering your modem up first. I wish we had more info though.

Comment: I solved this by simply unplugging the cable modem. One would think robust software would be able to handle this... :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have static IP, but without knowing the provider or info about your service then it is hard to tell. It could also be that you use PPPOE to connect to your provider but I am pretty sure it gives you an IP first so you can log in (it's been 9 years since i had service with pppoe). It could also be that your router is set to static when it should be dynamic, but again without how your router is setup that is just a guess.

Now that I think about it the aforementioned scenarios are unlikely.